# changing file permissions of default mkstemp

Tags: c, file, ubuntu-12.04, umask, mkstemp

I call the following code in C:

```
 fileCreatefd = mkstemp(fileName);
```

I see that the file is created with permissions 600 (-rw-------). I want to create this temp file as -rw-rw-rw-

I tried playing around with umask but that only applies a mask over the file permissions -- at least thats my understanding. So how can i create a file with permissions 666?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create it 0666 with mkstemp. You can change the permissions afterwards, if that is sufficient for your application, with fchmod.

```
fileCreatefd = mkstemp(fileName);
fchmod(fileCreatefd, 0666)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I am however curious. Why cant i create a file with 0666. Is it because gcc compilers post 2.0.7 wouldnt let me? I use 4.6.3 btw

Comment: POSIX specifies that mkstemp should create a file 0600; glibc (not gcc) implements this behaviour from 2.0.7. The intent is that mkstemp is used where a program needs a temporary file, and temporary files are not expected to be shared with / communicated to other users, so POSIX specifies private-by-default permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The `mkstemp()` function generates a unique temporary filename from template, creates  and  opens the file, and returns an open file descriptor for the file.

The  last six characters of template must be "XXXXXX" and these are replaced with a string that makes the filename unique.  Since it will be modified, template must not be a string  constant, but should be declared as a character array.

The  file is created with permissions `0600`, that is, read plus write for owner only.  (`In glibc versions 2.06 and earlier, the file is created with permissions 0666, that is, read  and  writefor  all users`.)  The returned file descriptor provides both read and write access to the file. The file is opened with the `open(2)` `O_EXCL` flag, guaranteeing that the caller  is  the  process that creates the file.

More generally, the POSIX specification of `mkstemp()` does not say anything about file modes, so the application should make sure its file mode creation mask (`umask(2)`) is set appropriately before calling `mkstemp()` (and `mkostemp()`).

So after creating the File Use `fchmod` to change the file permission.